# Python, sort a dict to represent a histogram

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a `dict` struture in python like this,

```
{'68': 1, '10': 2, '3': 1, '50': 1}
```

I would like to print out a histogram representing the `dict`. The problem is that I am not sure how to sort the `dict` in such a way as to produce the histogram.

I have seen many posts on how to sort a `dict` in increasing/decreasing order by either keys or values, but nothing to arrange it in a histogram format; where the largest value's key is in the center and the others are distributed on either side to create a nice mountain-ish looking graph.

Currently I can print out the `dict` in a histogram type format, but again, it is not sorted into a structure resembling histogram

Any ideas as to how I would sort my `dict` into a histogram? Maybe `numpy` or `collections` has something I do not know about?

Comment: The algorithm that comes to mind for me is: Take the keys, sort them, construct an array of length keys.size, assign each key an index starting in the middle of the array and moving forward and back. But I'd certainly check numpy first.

Comment: *"[...] and the others are distributed on either side [...]"* —how do you decide which side? you said keys with the largest values are in the center, but if the keys are just positive integers, there's no way to decide which positive integers belong to the left and which to the right... according to your description.

Comment: Just because some histograms look like a bell curve does not mean that they all do.  There is no histogram sort order.

Comment: Which represents the quantity - keys or values.?

Comment: [pandas.series.hist()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.hist.html) can plot a histogram from series data. It will count the occurrence of each value in the series and make a graph of the frequency, which is what a histogram is.

Comment: @wwii The values represent the quanity (ie the height of the bar if you were to graph it) The keys represent the "ticks" at the bottom of the graph. // @ Erik Allik & @ Paul hmm, I guess I didn't understand that, but viewing @ daenyths idea I think his makes sense. Start by handing out indexes, middle index receives the largest value, then alternate until none are left. But again, that might not be what a histogram is. //

Comment: @BumSkeeter: then what is the middle value of, say, `[1, 3, 7, 10, 20]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn the dictionary into a list of (key, value) tuples.

```
>>> d = {'68': 1, '10': 2, '3': 1, '50': 1}
>>> d = [(int(key), value) for key, value in d.iteritems()]
```

Sort the list by the first item of each tuple

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> d.sort(key = itemgetter(0))
>>> print d
[(3, 1), (10, 2), (50, 1), (68, 1)]
>>>
```

Comment: I ended up doing something along these lines. I used collections and did a `orderedDict`, it works out in very much the same way.

Comment: @BumSkeeter: so did you actually get a bell shaped curve?

Comment: Well, the data did produce a bell shape, I see what you mean that all data doesn't necessarily should though. It worked out very well. I had figured it should look like a bell because all of pictures that appear when searching histogram show a bell shaped curve.